# Sort ng-repeat grouping by boolean value

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

In my angular js attempt, I have a json :

```
[
  {
    "id": "1111",
    "peopleRelated": [
      {
        "summary": "Manager",
        "personName": "Suzanne",
        "personId": 382043,
        "rated" : true
      },
      {
        "summary": "VP",
        "personName": "Dave",
        "personId": 34532
        "rated" : false
      }

    ],
    "title": "Title1",    
  },
  {
    "id": "2222",
    "peopleRelated": [
      {
        "summary": "Manager",
        "personName": "Kevin",
        "personId": 38864
        "rated" : true
      }     
    ],
    "title": "Title2",    
  }
]
```

And html is following :

```
<div ng-repeat="mydata in data>
  <div ng-repeat="personData in mydata.peopleRelated">
  {{personData.personName}}
  <div>
</div>
```

I wish to sort the personName such as "rated=false" names appear first.
How should I go for this?
Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Not quite sure if this is what you're asking but

```
<div ng-repeat="personData in mydata.peopleRelated | orderBy:'rated'">
  {{personData.personName}} {{personData.rated}}
<div>
```

sorts the inner loop

Comment: @var17 not at all, see http://jsfiddle.net/9Ymvt/840/ Or you want to show false first per group

Comment: @Friso what happens if false stays into second part: http://jsfiddle.net/9Ymvt/840/

Comment: @MaximShoustin Not quite sure what you mean by that. I did state that I'm only sorting the inner loop. If you want to loose the context and sort the outer loop you'd need to write your own filter for that, like your fiddle does.

Comment: Hi Maxim, I just wanted to sort each individual inner loop by boolean value. Thanks for your input